# How to Display the Drop down list after clicking on Caret only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have one HTML design in that button/Portlet. I have one fa fa-Caret, After clicking on that caret it should display the drop-down list (which is hidden by default)

I have written a Jquery code to remove the hidden class of that drop-down list, But it's not working properly.

```js
$(".Caret").click(function () {
  if ($(".dropdown-menu").hasClass("hidden"))
    $(".dropdown-menu").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i id="carett" class="fa fa-caret-down pull-right hidden Caret"></i > ' + ButtonName + '</a >
  <ul id="ddlist1" class="dropdown-menu hidden">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Whenever I click that Button's Caret symbol only that drop-down list must appear, and if I switch to another Button's Caret(Second button I didn't mention) that drop down must come, I have a static drop down, but I am adding into the number of buttons (Generated dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Note:- You need to add `span` class and inside `span` class you can write `<i>` and add toggle class on `<span>` tag resolve this issue.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="dropdown">
  <span  class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  </span>
  <ul id="ddlist1" class="dropdown-menu hidden">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: that entire thing means Person name and Caret are adjacent to each other like. <li +PersonName+><a><i class="Caret"></i></a><ul id="dropdown"><li><a>Setting</a></li></ul></li>    If I modified my code like u mention, It will get disturbed.

Answer (score 0):

Click event triggered from 'anchor' tag. Also you could use the inline style 'display' property too.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i id="carett" class="fa fa-caret-down pull-right hidden Caret"></i > ' + ButtonName + '</a >
  <ul id="ddlist1" class="dropdown-menu" style="display:none">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>

<script>
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
  if ($(".dropdown-menu").css("display") == "none")
    $(".dropdown-menu").css("display", "block");
});
</script>
```